# JasperReports Embed Data in JRXML without any dataSource

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to embed data in report template(jrxml) without any dataSource.I want to write my data staticly in jrxml,аnd display the table with this data. It is really possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can have a list variable and store the data in it using Java class.

1. Create a variable with variable class list or collection.
2. Put in the variable expression the Java method which returns the list.

If you are using groovy same thing can be achieved Groovy Collection. Here's more if you want to learn about [groovy collections](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Collections) .

For Example :

**Have a parameter/variable in report**

```
<parameter name="list_collect" class="java.util.List" isForPrompting="false">
  <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[(new beandatasource()).OnFlyCollection()]]>                    </defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

**And the Java Class**

```
package beandatasource;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class OnFlyCollection {

    public ArrayList<String> ListCollect() {

        ArrayList<String> arr_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        arr_list.add("A");
        arr_list.add("B");
        arr_list.add("C");

        return arr_list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @cjava! I need exactly same thing: inline my data in report template just to expport some text in excel. Our platform is not Java. Could you please specify how to embed java collection code in report template jrxml?

Comment: @cjava. Yes I think this is work for static data.My data is dynamic. I need to embed java code in jrxml not in class. I wanted to get the array of records with variable/parameter not using java class. It is really possible?

Comment: Ofcourse you can make the data in the java class dynamic. But I don't think you can embed an external tag in the jrxml for data.

Comment: @cjava, and what about embeding in jrmxl a scriptlet with definition class of one record for my table?Is it possible?

Comment: @Fantomas For Scriplets also you will have to add the external java class .The java class that i have shown in the example itself can be used to connect to database retrieve result and then return back the list to the report variable.

Comment: @cjava. I have a problem. My data is a dynamic array and I don't know how my data are link with fields. Solution is to hava a Java class thas describes the data fields. It turns that this Java class must be dynamic. Only the way is to embed the java code in jrxml. Not use the jar file. I don't find the answer how to make it. Probably I can parse my data to JSON string and use it for datasource embed in jrxml. Is it possible?