# JasperReports JRXML Embed Array of records in jrxml

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm trying to **embed** in jrxml array of records for my table. I think I can use a variable expression in Ireport for it. I know how to create one record for my table but I don't know how to create many records **not using Java class**. My data it not static. They are dymanic.

I need to programmly create jxml template. And our platform is not Java. I want to create a JavaCollection- array of records in variable expression and use this collection as JrBeanCollectionDatasource for my table. And then use $F{field_name} to retrieve the data from this bean. It is really possible?

Comment: We are implementing excel exporter for report screens. We need to embed report data (table dataset data) into report template as Java objects or something

Comment: We are not on a Java platform. We use Jasper Reports REST API

Comment: possible duplicate of [JasperReports Embed Data in JRXML without any dataSource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053454/jasperreports-embed-data-in-jrxml-without-any-datasource)